# Android Grid View image size according to screen density

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

The grid view of my application has 4 rows and 4 columns. 
I want this to fill half screen ,irrespective of the screen size of the device.
How can i set the image view size accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define size of image view in dp,which will set the size according to screen density.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set the size of the GridView in dip (device-independent pixels). You can do this via your XML layout file, explicitly or with the help of the visual editor. As device-independent pixels are essentially percentiles, the Android platform will handle resizing for you based on the size and density of the device displaying. In order words, a value of android:layout_width="50dip" will look the same on any device.

Comment: thanks for answer.. image are within grid view,so what should is set the size of the images so that they look same irrespective to screen size.